# Unable to get rid of www prefix in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite all following urls in Apache (v2.2.22 - Debian):

> http://mydomain.com/something
>
> http://www.mydomain.com/something
>
> https://www.mydomain.com/something

to

> https://mydomain.com/something

Rewriting http to https is no problem - this works fine. But I don't seem to be able to get rid of the www prefix. My domain does run with the www, however my SSL certificate happens to be only valid for mydomain.com and mail.mydomain.com and not for www.mydomain.com - so the www gives me SSL warnings in my browser.

I have tried many suggestions on the Web, which all didn't seem to work. Currently in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default (picked up by apache2.conf) is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://mydomain.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [L]
```

As I said, this works for http => https, not for losing the www prefix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to do an external redirect. Add the `[R=301]` flag.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: @planck You need 301 on both the rules.